# Imports Excel File in GridView (Editing ans searching)

Tags: asp.net

does anyone know how to load an Excel file to a asp.net application? And GriView charged you can edit and search data in GridView?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430).
Then you can easily do it something like this:

```
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

Though to avoid hustles with a different versions of Microsoft office and to have cleaner code, I suggest you to install netoffice wrapper from [here](http://netoffice.codeplex.com/)

Look at the demos and examples.